# Multiselect value is printing only the first character

Tags: php, arrays

The table rows are generated based on the count of $getActivity. The problem I'm facing is after submitting the form, **the multiselect(name="responsible_person[]") value is printing only the first character** instead of displaying the options selected by the user. FYI, the textbox(assigned_by) value is printing as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
    <form method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/Planning/updatedetails">
    <table>
    <?php foreach ($getActivities as $getActivity):?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="assigned_by[]" value=""></td>
            <td><select class="form-control selectpicker" id="responsible_person" name="responsible_person[]" multiple data-live-search="true">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
    </form>
```

```
    public function updatedetails(){

    $assigned_by = $this->input->post('assigned_by');
    $responsible_person = implode(",", $this->input->post('responsible_person'));
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($batch_id);$i++)
    {
        $dataSet[] = array (
          'assigned_by' => $assigned_by[$i],
          'responsible_person' => $responsible_person[$i]
        );  
    }   
    print_r($dataSet);
   }
```

Current Result Format:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [assigned_by] => Test1 [responsible_person] => O) [1] => Array ( [assigned_by] => Test2 [responsible_person] => p)[2] => Array ( [assigned_by] => Test3 [responsible_person] => t))
```

Expected format:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [assigned_by] => Test1 [responsible_person] => Option1,option2) [1] => Array ( [assigned_by] => Test2 [responsible_person] => Option 1)[2] => Array ( [assigned_by] => Test3 [responsible_person] => ))
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What is the desired format of `$dataSet`? Your `$responsible_person` variable is a string (that's what `implode` returns) and then you access a single character of that string in your `for` loop through the counter. Not quite sure what your code is supposed to achieve, so please include these details.

Comment: You've imploded the posted `responsible_person` array into a string so `$responsible_person[$i]` will be an offset of that string 1 character.

Comment: @El_Vanja I've updated with desired format. Please have a look. Need to get the multiselect options selected by the user.

Comment: I believe you should simply be imploding inside the loop.

Comment: @El_Vanja I tried with 'responsible_person' => implode(",", $this->input->post('responsible_person'))[$i], inside the loop. didn't work

Comment: Please show a dump of `$this->input->post('responsible_person')`.

Comment: array(5) { [0]=> string(26) "EC 02-First Name Last Name" [1]=> string(17) "EC-26-Raju Welder" [2]=> string(27) "EC 01-First Name, Last Name" [3]=> string(17) "EC-26-Raju Welder" [4]=> string(6) "Others" }

Comment: @El_Vanja Above is the var_dump result.

Comment: @AbraCadaver What do you suggest?

Comment: Ah, now I noticed your error. You say you tried `'responsible_person' => implode(",", $this->input->post('responsible_person'))[$i]`, with that you merely access the string character again. If you move that index access inside like this: `'responsible_person' => implode(",", $this->input->post('responsible_person')[$i])` you'll actually be accessing the element of the array.

Comment: Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: Getting the above error. Also, the value for responsible_person is empty when printing now

Comment: My bad, I wrote that before loading the comments you made in the meantime (with the dump of the input). Your results are already strings, there is nothing to implode. Just use them directly.

Comment: When using it's printing the first character only, that's the problem.

Comment: Also, there is no `$batch_id` defined in or passed into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a multidimensional array to group the text and select with the same key `$key` and then dynamically create an array `[]` of that array of the multiple selections:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/Planning/updatedetails">
<table>
<?php foreach ($getActivities as $key => $getActivity):?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="assigned_by[<?= $key ?>]" value=""></td>
        <td><select name="responsible_person[<?= $key ?>][]" class="form-control selectpicker" id="responsible_person"  multiple data-live-search="true">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
</form>
```

In this example with 2 text inputs and 2 selects, the `$_POST` would look something like this with multiple selections per select:

```
Array
(
    [assigned_by] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )
    [responsible_person] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Option 1
                    [1] => Option 2
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Option 2
                    [1] => Option 3
                )
        )
)
```

Notice that `$batch_id` does not exist, so just loop one (`$assigned_by` in this case) and use the key to access the select and `implode` that one:

```
public function updatedetails()
{
    $assigned_by = $this->input->post('assigned_by');
    $responsible_person = $this->input->post('responsible_person');

    foreach($assigned_by as $key => $val) 
    {
        $dataSet[] = array (
          'assigned_by' => $val,
          'responsible_person' => implode(',', $responsible_person[$key])
        );  
    }   
    print_r($dataSet);
}
```